# How to get the session dbus to use /run for its socket?

Tags: dbus

In an X11 session, my session dbus uses `/run/user/1000/bus` for its socket. When I launch a dbus session in ssh with `dbus-launch` it creates a socket in /tmp and it seems to be by design as `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf` contains a section

```
<listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>
```

My problem is, that I'd like to use a sandboxed program, that doesn't have access to the system /tmp, so programs using dbus-launch should create sockets either in a folder in $HOME or in /run/user/$UID.

How do I configure that /run should be used for dbus sockets by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for now is editing that file to user another directory. One needs to be root and take care that no system package overwrites the changes, but it works and doesn't seem to cause side effects with other programs.